# ServiceNow history is not showing 'List' option

Tags: servicenow

We are using Servicenow helsinki version.
For some of the tables both list and calender options are present, but for few forms only calender option is present.Just wanted to know how can we show both the options.[image]
Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option for **History** > **List** only appears for tables that have auditing enabled.

For a knowledge article on this one take a look at [Enable auditing for a table](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/helsinki-servicenow-platform/page/administer/security/task/t_EnableAuditingForATable.html).

In brief, you can enable it this way

- Go to **System Definition** > **Dictionary**
- Choose a table to enable auditing on from the list
- Check the **Audit** checkbox
- **Save** / **Update** the record

Then go to a record on that table, and verify it is enabled.

I just tested this on the *Power Equipment [cmdb_ci_power_eq]* table and worked.